# Two Instance of membership provider in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-membership, membership-provider, membership

I am in between of some application and found one scenario which i can not get through.

In my ASP.NET 2.0 webiste, i have implemented membership for user management. I currently have two providers registered in web.config file.

- Provider for Active Directory - **Default**
- Provider Connected with SQL DB

As i mentioned, my default provider is active directory provider. My server just got disconnected for maintenance and i found that my web site started throwing exceptions. As my default provider is active directory one, when i try to get secondary provider which is actually for SQL db,

> var oProvider = Membership.Providers["MyMembershipProvider"];

my application throws error "**The server is not operational.**"

I suspect that when i execute the above line of code, membership creates instances for all the registered providers.

**Question:**

Is there any way i can create object of the particular provider registered in web.config and avoid this error?

How can i create a dynamic object of provider from the provider name?

How can i ignore the providers which are not accessible or down?